# Java - Stack.pop does not return last item added

Tags: java, android

In teaching myself Android programming (using Android Studio) I am working on a basic calculator app. My eval method uses Dijkstra's shunting-yard algorithm to parse a string expression and calculate the result. I got the idea for this from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form).

The code for my Evaluator class is as follows:

```
class Evaluator {
    private static Evaluator instance = new Evaluator();

    private Stack< String > mOperators;
    private Stack< Double > mOperands;

    public static Evaluator getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private Evaluator() {
        mOperands = new Stack< Double >();
        mOperators = new Stack< String >();
    }

    public Double eval( String expression ) {
        Stack stack = convertExpressionToStack( expression );
        buildOperationStacks( stack );
        return doEval();
    }

    private Double doEval() {
        while ( !mOperators.isEmpty() ) {
            String op = mOperators.pop();
            Double v = mOperands.pop();

            switch ( op ) {
                case "+":
                    v = mOperands.pop() + v;
                    break;
                case "-":
                    v = mOperands.pop() - v;
                    break;
                case "*":
                    v = mOperands.pop() * v;
                    break;
                case "/":
                    v = mOperands.pop() / v;
                    break;
            }

            mOperands.push( v );
        }

        return mOperands.pop();
    }

    private void buildOperationStacks( Stack stack ) {
        while ( !stack.isEmpty() ) {
            String s = ( String ) stack.pop();

            switch ( s ) {
                case "+":
                case "-":
                case "*":
                case "x":
                case "X":
                case "/":
                case "÷":
                    if ( s.equals( "x" ) || s.equals( "X" ) ) {
                        s = "*";
                    } else if ( s.equals( "÷" ) ) {
                        s = "/";
                    }

                    mOperators.push( s );
                    break;
                default:
                    try {
                        if ( !stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek().equals  ( "." ) ) {
                            s += stack.pop();
                            s += stack.pop();
                        }

                        mOperands.push( Double.parseDouble( s ) );
                    } catch ( Exception e ) {
                        Log.e( "Error", e.getMessage() );
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    private Stack convertExpressionToStack( String expression ) {
        Stack< String > s = new Stack< String >();

        for ( char c : expression.toCharArray() ) {
            s.push( String.valueOf( c ) );
        }

        return s;
    }
}
```

So my issue is in the doEval method. When I pop the elements off each stack I am getting the first elements added to each stack. I was of the impression that stacks were a First In Last Out structure.

So what might I be doing wrong? Do I need to somehow reverse each stack?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

So for example, I input 5+3*2. I would expect the execution to be

```
pass 1: value1 = 2, Operator1 = *, value2 = 3 result = 6
pass 2: Value1 = 6 (result of pass 1) Operator1 = +, value2 = 5 result = 11
```

However, when I debug this, I am seeing:

```
pass 1: value1 = 5, Operator1 = +, value2 = 3, result = 8
pass 2: value1 = 8 (result of pass 1), operator1 = *, value2 = 2, result = 16
```

Comment: a stack is a LIFO, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Comment: @RC. - I agree with you. First In Last Out is the same as Last In First Out. However, my stacks are acting as First In First Out. I don't understand why they are behaving this way

Comment: LIFO is not the same as FILO? But you are correct that it does not matter whether you are using lifo or filo. But it is not the same

Comment: Your understanding of stack is correct, the error lies somewhere in the logic of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `convertExpressionToStack()` method is building an operand stack in the correct order, and then your `buildOperstionStack()` method is inverting it, by popping one and pushing the other.

You don't really need this second method anyway: just change the evaluation method to understand `x` as multiplication, etc.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the info. I will implement this now.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of Stack is correct. It's First In, Last Our or Last In, First Out.

About your code:

```
while ( !mOperators.isEmpty() ) {
            String op = mOperators.pop();
            Double v = mOperands.pop();

            switch ( op ) {
                case "+":
                    v = mOperands.pop() + v;
                    break;
                case "-":
                    v = mOperands.pop() - v;
                    break;
                case "*":
                    v = mOperands.pop() * v;
                    break;
                case "/":
                    v = mOperands.pop() / v;
                    break;
            }

            mOperands.push( v );
        }
```

Since, you have not mentioned, how exactly is it behaving, so, let me explain. Suppose, mOperators has +,- where + was added first and - on top of +

```
mOperands has 3,6,2,1
```

This is how your code will and should behave.

For the first iteration of while loop:

```
op = -
v = 1
v = 2-1 = 1 // since it's a -

mOperands is now: 3,6
```

and after call, mOperands.push(v), since v now is 1, your mOperands will be:

3,6,1

Second iteration of while loop:

```
op = +
v = 1
v = 6+1 = 7 // since op is +
```

Your mOperands now looks like: 3

And once it breaks from switch, it will make mOperands as:

3,7

P.S: You should debug your application to see values of mOperands at each and every step to get better idea, why it's behaving like it is.

Comment: Thank you. I am debugging my app and I will edit my question to show an example.